# Adjust UIView down 20px in NavigationController after SetStatusBarHidden is called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

This is very similar to other questions I've seen here, when you hide the statusbar using the Setstatusbarhidden method, the view inside the navigation controller moves up 20px but the navigation bar does not.  This causes the content inside of the viewcontroller to go behind the navigation bar and the top 20px gets clipped.

Most people want to move the navigation bar up to fill the whole screen, but I don't.  I want to replace the status bar with a notification bar for a moment.  I want the view in the viewController to remain at it's pre-statusbar-removal location.

I've tried adjusting the frame of the view, y -= 20, and after that failed, adjusting the frame of the UIViewControllerWrapperView, y -= 20 to no avail.  I know there are some libraries that will do this sort of thing but I want to keep it simple and do it myself.

Thanks for the help.